# OpenVPN on ec2 bridged mode connects but no Ping, DNS or forwarding

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn

I am trying to use OpenVPN to access the internet over a secure connection.

I have openVPN configured and running on Amazon EC2 in bridge mode with client certs. I can successfully connect from the client, but I cannot get access to the internet or ping anything from the client

I checked the following and everything seems to shows a successful connection between the vpn client/server and UDP traffic on 1194

```
[server] sudo tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 1194
      (shows UDP traffic after establishing connection)

[server] sudo iptables -L

    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

[server] sudo iptables -L -t nat

    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-W-X-Y-0.us-west-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination


[server] openvpn.log
    Wed Oct 19 03:11:26 2011 localhost/a.b.c.d:61905 [localhost] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
    Wed Oct 19 03:11:26 2011 localhost/a.b.c.d:61905 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Re-using SSL/TLS context
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 LZO compression initialized
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '360696c5'
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '13a273ba'
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:31 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:57889, sid=dd886604 ab6ebb38
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:35 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=EXAMPLE/CN=EXAMPLE_CA/emailAddress=info@EXAMPLE.com
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:35 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=EXAMPLE/CN=localhost/emailAddress=info@EXAMPLE.com
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:37 2011 a.b.c.d:57889 [localhost] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:57889
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:39 2011 localhost/a.b.c.d:57889 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:39 2011 localhost/a.b.c.d:57889 SENT CONTROL [localhost]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway W.X.Y.Z,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig W.X.Y.Z 255.255.255.0' (status=1)
    Wed Oct 19 03:41:40 2011 localhost/a.b.c.d:57889 MULTI: Learn: (IPV6) -> localhost/a.b.c.d:57889

[client] tracert google.com
    Tracing route to google.com [74.125.71.104] over a maximum of 30 hops:
      1   347 ms   349 ms   348 ms  PC [w.X.Y.Z]
      2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I can also successfully ping the server IP address from the client, and ping google.com from an SSH shell on the server. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my config (Note: W.X.Y.Z == amazon EC2 private ipaddress)

bridge config on br0

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ifconfig br0 W.X.Y.X netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast W.X.Y.255 up
route add default gw W.X.Y.1 br0
```

/etc/openvpn/server.conf (from https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openvpn.html)

```
local W.X.Y.Z
dev tap0
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"
;server W.X.Y.0 255.255.255.0
server-bridge W.X.Y.Z 255.255.255.0 W.X.Y.105 W.X.Y.200
;push "route W.X.Y.0 255.255.255.0" 
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
user nobody
group nogroup 
log-append openvpn.log
```

iptables config

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s W.X.Y.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Routing Tables added

```
route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    W.X.Y.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
    0.0.0.0         W.X.Y.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0

C:>route print
    ===========================================================================
    Interface List
     32...00 ff ac d6 f7 04 ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
     15...00 14 d1 e9 57 49 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
     14...00 14 d1 e9 57 49 ......Realtek RTL8191SU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Net
    work Adapter
     10...00 1f d0 50 1b ca ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
      1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
     11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
     16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
     17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
     18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
     36...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
    ===========================================================================

    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.2.1       10.1.2.201     25
             10.1.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.1.2.201    281
           10.1.2.201  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.2.201    281
           10.1.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.2.201    281
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.1.2.201    281
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.2.201    281
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.2.1  Default
    ===========================================================================

C:>tracert google.com

    Tracing route to google.com [74.125.71.147]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

      1   344 ms   345 ms   343 ms  PC [W.X.Y.221]
      2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: $100 says this is a routing error

Comment: append the routing table on the client `route print` and on the server `route -n`?

Comment: routing tables added

Comment: Is client running Windows 7?

Comment: yes. sorry, should have added that in the post

Answer (score 0):

I think, mistake is in bridge definition. 
Bridge must consist of eth0-device and tap0-device.

For MY example it`s so:

```
brctl show br0

bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.000c29af7f50   no      tap1
                            eth2
```

Bridge-device has in IP 10.1.2.1 (from your example) and iptables (FORWARD-chain is default ACCEPT in your example):

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.1.2.0/24  anywhere
```

So client with 10.1.2.201 will have MASQUERADE-action on OpenVPN server.

Config of openvpn-server must have (for example):

```
server-bridge 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.2 10.1.2.200
```